# HTML Codes Not Work for Excel 2007

Tags: html, excel, cognos

I am working on a project in Cognos Report Studio version 10.2.1. But my issue is the same when using 10.1.
I am having an issue when switching output from Excel 2002 to Excel 2007. There is an HTML item on my report form that does some formatting to the output.  The codes are shown below.  These codes work well with Excel 2002 but do NOT work at all with Excel 2007.

---

```
<style>
@page
{
margin:.50in .50in .50in .50in;
mso-header-margin:0in;
mso-footer-margin:0in;
mso-page-orientation:Landscape;
mso-horizontal-page-align:center;
mso-vertical-page-align:top;}
</style>

<x:ExcelWorksheets>
<x:WorksheetOptions>
<x:FitToPage/>
<x:Print>
<x:ValidPrinterInfo/>
</x:Print>
<x:DoNotDisplayGridlines/>
</x:WorksheetOptions>
```

Comment: Nothing you can do about it, as far as I know.  I had a few customers complain bitterly about this, and I spent a good deal of time digging into it, but never got anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for sharing your experience!

Comment: Could it have something to do with the different file type:  xls vs xlsx?  Could it be that somewhere in Cognos it has logic like:  if output is xls, fire the html code; else do nothing?

Comment: Excel 2002 output is actually creating an MHTML file, and I've always assumed that's why the formatting tags worked.  Excel 2007 is a binary XLS file, which is an entirely different animal.